# Contents are missing in tool window in pycharm. how do I add it?

Tags: window, pycharm, toolbar, file-get-contents

I clicked something and then my contents are missing.
It disappeared. how do I call it again?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4iJY.png)